# Ignited Datatables edit_column call back function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I'm using the Data Table Libray written by "Vincent Bambico and Yusuf Ozdemir"
https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

I've looked at the support information available here http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160896/

I'm having trouble with the edit Column function.

```
function paging()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('Datatables'); 

    $this->datatables->select('id, name, visit_date, date_created, postcode, order_total, status')
        ->from('day_orders')
        ->edit_column('status','$1', 'callback_cap(status)')
        ->edit_column('date_created','$1', 'callback_date(date_created)');       
    echo $this->datatables->generate();

}

public function cap($i)
{
    return ucfirst($i);
}

public function date($i)
{
    return date('d-m-Y', $i);   
}
```

Rather than the data being output to the json string all I'm getting is the text I input as the third param so "callback_date(date_created)" for example. Not really sure what I'm doing wrong? any ideas?

Edit: 
The problem seem to be that the library can't find any of my call back functions. The code example above is all wrapped in a class. I've tried putting the call back function in a few different places including inside the lib file, but I'm still not having any luck.

When we get down to checking if the function exists via "function_exists" no function can be found. I've done some research and I think the issue is due to the class structure I'm using but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

create helper file contain your method callback_date($date_created)

then after loading helper you can use method in edit_column or add_column

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is one year old. But I faced the same scenario today and just though I would share here what I found and how I fixed this same issue. It will hopefully help someone.

I downloaded the latest version of Ignited Datatables library from Github.

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

Then, I found this solution in the following [blog](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-use-callback-function-in-ignited.html?showComment=1454656281146#c8008121845968217812).  Although it had a few bugs and issues, I easily got them fixed by myself and made it work.

What you have to do is include your callback function as a helper function.

Save this in application/helpers/my_datatable_helper.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/** 
*  edit_column callback function in Codeigniter (Ignited Datatables)
*
* Grabs a value from the edit_column field for the specified field so you can
* return the desired value.  
*
* @access   public
* @return   mixed
*/

if ( ! function_exists('check_status'))
{
    function check_status($status = '')
    {
        return ($status == 1) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
    }   
}

/* End of file MY_datatable_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/MY_datatable_helper.php */
```

Then in your controller, before you call the edit_column method, load this helper as shown below.

```
$this->load->library('Datatables');
$this->load->helper('My_datatable_helper');

$this->datatables->edit_column('is_active','$1', '$this->test(is_active)');
```

Hope this helps :)